# Using both fixed effects and random effects in r metafor package

Tags: r, mixed-model, meta-analysis, metafor

Hi there :) I am trying to run a meta analysis using rma.uni in the metafor package in r but cannot work out how to add both fixed effects (eg bird migration status) and random effects (eg species, habitat type etc.) in the same model, is this possible to do this or would I need to use a different package? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `rma.uni()` function doesn't allow you to add random effects (beyond the estimate-level random effects that are automatically added). You should look into the `rma.mv()` function, which provides full control over the random effects that can added. See here for the documentation of the function:

https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/rma.mv.html

and the links therein for examples.